# interface{} to []byte conversion in golang

Tags: json, go

I am trying to unmarshal data which is of type interface. So I need to convert the interface type to `[]byte` and pass it to unmarshal.
I tried

1. `err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(kpi), &a)` => failed
2. to convert the interface to `[]byte` using
   `kpidata, res := kpi.([]byte)` => failed, `kpidata` is `nil`

So is there any way we can convert it?

Example: https://play.golang.org/p/5pqQ0DQ94Dp

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/4UzKazRVYBE

Comment: `[]byte(fmt.Sprint(data)` // where data is interface{}.

Answer (score 25):

In your [sample](https://play.golang.org/p/H-YeAcik-Xu) code `data` should be **JSON-encoded** (in simple word **[String](https://play.golang.org/p/uQPwJrwJO-3)**) so you are using `Unmarshal` in a wrong way:

> ```
> // Unmarshal parses the JSON-encoded data and stores the result
> // in the value pointed to by v. If v is nil or not a pointer,
> // Unmarshal returns an InvalidUnmarshalError.
> func Unmarshal(data []byte, v interface{}) error
> ```

Try it on [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/j-cjmoFpden) and [this: `[]string{"art", "football"}`](https://play.golang.org/p/alucDPcVZwU):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    // ********************* Marshal *********************
    u := map[string]interface{}{}
    u["name"] = "kish"
    u["age"] = 28
    u["work"] = "engine"
    //u["hobbies"] = []string{"art", "football"}
    u["hobbies"] = "art"

    b, err := json.Marshal(u)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(b))

    // ********************* Unmarshal *********************
    var a interface{}
    err = json.Unmarshal(b, &a)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

output:

```
{"age":28,"hobbies":"art","name":"kish","work":"engine"}
map[name:kish work:engine age:28 hobbies:art]
```

---

You want to **Unmarshal** it, so try [this](https://play.golang.org/p/C2nhrdG3gN8) simple working example (`[]byte(kpi.(string))`):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var kpi interface{} = st
    var a []Animal
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(kpi.(string)), &a)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(a)
}

type Animal struct {
    Name  string
    Order string
}

var st = `[
    {"Name": "Platypus", "Order": "Monotremata"},
    {"Name": "Quoll",    "Order": "Dasyuromorphia"}
]`
```

output:

```
[{Platypus Monotremata} {Quoll Dasyuromorphia}]
```

---

Working [example](https://play.golang.org/p/CykdkWtXklN) using (`[]byte(*kpi.(*string))`):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var kpi interface{} = &st
    var a []Animal
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(*kpi.(*string)), &a)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(a)
}

type Animal struct {
    Name  string
    Order string
}

var st = `[
    {"Name": "Platypus", "Order": "Monotremata"},
    {"Name": "Quoll",    "Order": "Dasyuromorphia"}
]`
```

---

[Marshal](https://play.golang.org/p/tKkMrY5G5RS):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    u := map[string]interface{}{}
    u["1"] = "one"
    b, err := json.Marshal(u)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(b))
}
```

output:

```
{"1":"one"}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Way too complicated. matthias krull solved it above.

Comment: we get panic error   
code:     err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(kpi.(string)), &a)
" panic: interface conversion: interface is map[string]interface {}, not string "

Comment: @kish do you have `map[string]interface {}` type and need to `Marshal`? note: `Unmarshal` needs `[]byte` of `string` as input not  `map[string]interface {}` . so for better help provide minimum [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org) sample code.

Comment: I am unable to provide the code sample as it is huge source code. but i will try to explain it.
I will get exactly as below in interface format(as we dont know the exact amount data and type of data so we use interface)
map[name: kish age:28 work: engine hobbies:[art football]] and some times as map[name: kish age:28 work: engine hobbies: art].
Once i receive it, i need to unmarshall it .
So i need to convert it to []byte style for unmarshal function.

Comment: See new edit. [I hope this helps.](https://play.golang.org/p/j-cjmoFpden)

Comment: `data` should be **JSON-encoded** (in simple word **[String](https://play.golang.org/p/uQPwJrwJO-3)**) so you are using `Unmarshal` in a wrong way

Comment: @A.R i understood your point. But even in your link when we try to print it we are getting as map[* : *]. How to prevent the map? this map is trying to create problem when i use the data for dynamic mapping in elasticsearch.

Comment: What do you mean by "How to prevent the map?". what problem it creates? you should elaborate. and I think it is new question so [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ask in new Question clearly, so someone could help.

Answer (score 10):

Working example based on the one provided by Kugel:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func passInterface(v interface{}) {
    b, ok := v.(*[]byte)
    fmt.Println(ok)
    fmt.Println(b)
}

func main() {
    passInterface(&[]byte{0x00, 0x01, 0x02})
}
```

[Play](https://play.golang.org/p/4UzKazRVYBE)

If you do not pass references, it will work basically the same:

[Play](https://play.golang.org/p/GSd7LeFRB_y)

Comment: 1. we get the compilation error,
    code: passInterface(&kpi)
 err := json.Unmarshal(kpi, &a)
         your function


   2. error : cannot use kpi (type interface {}) as type []byte in argument to json.Unmarshal: need type assertion

Comment: It is pretty hard to debug your issues without the actual code, really. Even a boiled down version for the go playground would do.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do. If you have a map already it seems you either have to unmarshal certain members: [like this](https://play.golang.org/p/M8-sDQV-HCL) or [like this](https://play.golang.org/p/fDF8Br2ub1K) or you do not need to unmarshal anything and only need the correct type assertion in case the value of the `{}interface` is structured data already.